# How to send data to influxdb via post call without using curl?

Tags: http, curl, influxdb

i am new to influxdb and i was trying to add data to influx db . I found on the documentation page that it can be done using curl.

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000'
```

but i want to hit it from the browser and be able to insert data to influxdb.

For select query :

```
http://localhost:8086/query?db=mydb&q=select * from temperature
```

this is a url which can be used to get data from influxdb. Is there a similar way to insert data to influxdb.
I tried creating url from curl but wasn't successful.

Comment: In order to send POST request in browser manually, you need to use browser plugin such as Postman or RESTClient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

little bit late but:

you should call REST via POST

```
url: http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb
type :POST
body: measurement,value=123 thetime=1502474399000
```